# How could the Tayan keep its victims from moving?

Tags: internal-consistency, xenobiology

Below the surface of Dalia, there exists a monstrous beast that eats humanoids alive. This creature is called the Tayan. The Tayan is 150 feet tall, and 35 feet wide. It nests itself underground, and waits silently for prey to fall into its gaping mandibles, to be swallowed and digested.

Prey inside the Tayan are alive throughout the entire digestion process. The Tayan puts tiny tendrils inside intelligent victims brains, that act as a dialysis machine keeping them alive, and feeding them nutrients.

But the Tayan has to keep victims from moving around, as that could complicate the process, and victims could create injuries for the Tayan. So the Tayan has to have a way to keep victims from moving. So, my question is, how could the Tayan keep victims from moving inside its stomach.

***Criteria***

Whatever method you make, it has to have a small flaw that could allow one human (most likely my main character) from being unable to move.

Comment: Please check your criteria: you cannot call flaw the intended result of keeping the humanoid still.

Comment: so.... Your humanoid character has what? Is he a mutant? A cyborg? a Paralytic individual? a Average Joe? Superman maybe? DEADPOOL? There are answers here based on guesses on your hero. If Joe goes in the Taiyan he is dead, but if theres some miracle that can occure, Joe might live. But if Superman gets eaten by the Taiyan, then he will just blast the creature into smitherins.

Comment: @Mr.J. Totally normal human

Comment: @RobertPaul you already mentioned that the Taiyan has a  "wet, fleshy sack with no light "  https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/124057/how-to-make-religious-sacrifices-to-their-dark-god-sympathetic from this question, you already have a good idea that nobody can move from the stomach, what more are you asking for?

Answer (score 6):

**Interrupting the spinal cord at the base of the brain will paralyze.**

If your creature puts tiny tendrils inside the victims brains, it would be an easy thing to paralyze them with this same intervention.  Intercepting / interrupting motor nerves on their way out of the brain would accomplish this.  This is how quadriplegics get paralyzed - the nerve tracts leading down from the brain is disrupted or injured.

An interesting side note - if the Tayan tendrils entered at the brainstem the face would not be paralyzed.  People could move their mouths and eyes etc - this is how quadriplegics can use computers and wheelchairs other other devices manipulated with their mouths or eyes.

Maybe your hero is already a quadriplegic.  It is good for heroes to have a flaw.  Perhaps he has implanted robot actuators for his limbs that he controls directly from the brain (which is very nearly a real thing now).

Or maybe your hero escapes because he keeps his head, is limber, and has sharp teeth.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your past questions: **Stomach Walls**

As each person is eaten whole by the taiyan, they slide through the esophagus into the stomach of the creature, never to see light again.

As for your human to survive

**NONE**

As you have elaborately describe the insides of the creature

"*Nobles and high priests often sacrifice slaves into the Tayan’s maw, 
where they can expect to spend 5-30 years inside the Tayans stomach, slowly being digested in agony and pain*"

They also tried everything to kill the creature, but could not, that's why the taiyan was considered a **GOD**

[SOURCE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/124057/28224)

Answer (score 0):

**TENTACLES, TENTACLES, AND MORE TENTACLES**

This is heavily based on an answer to a different question. [Here's the link to the answer that is the original inspiration for this.](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/170479/94891)

> The Tayan puts tiny tendrils inside intelligent victims brains, that act as a dialysis machine keeping them alive, and feeding them nutrients.

The answer here is simple. You make the tiny tendrils mentioned above much larger and increase their numbers. Then, you make the tendrils do more than just act as dialysis machines; they also wrap around and thoroughly ensnare the victim.

The tentacles hold the victim off the walls of the stomach, ensuring that they have no leverage with which to free themselves regardless of strength. They also can't really attack the tentacles with teeth, fingernails, and such because the tentacles are constantly moving and can easily maintain their grip while avoiding the hands, feet, and mouth. And even if a victim gets lucky, the tentacles are smooth and covered with slippery saliva, making pulling hard enough to break them nearly impossible. And even if the victim gets lucky and manages to do enough damage to a tentacle to render it useless, there are plenty more to take its place.

Moreover, the victim would struggle to gather their strength because the tentacles would be coiled around their bodies, and could easily apply some light constriction that impairs breathing and leaves the victim constantly out of breath. The tentacles could also prevent victims from communicating with each other by gagging them or constraining their breathing.

And the tentacles could constantly churn the victim around, ensuring they are too disoriented to focus on any one thing. Even if the victim did free himself, he wouldn't be able to tell which direction he'd fall; a very paralyzing thing for people evolved from monkeys with good reason to fear death by falling from a tree.

Also, the victim would be unable to hide any tools, weapons, or other nasty surprises, as the tentacles will thoroughly search every inch of the body over and over, even checking under loose clothing. The victims won't be able to hide stuff on certain unspecified parts of themselves that they are reasonably certain won't be searched, because the tentacles are going to search those parts of you anyway, your dignity be damned.

Also, the slippery saliva-like substance mentioned earlier? That stuff could be the Tayan's digestive juices, and the tentacles will thoroughly coat the victim in the substance. If it were just a normal stomach, a victim might try to climb the stomach walls to get out of the pool of digestive juices near the bottom. But since the stomach has digestive juice-coated tendrils that grip the victims, the victim can't climb out of the digestive juices; all they can do is do their best to ignore the pain the acid causes.

The dialysis machine bit could be implemented by having each tentacle tipped with a stinger that can inject nutrients when the victim needs to be 'fed'. Of course, the stingers in question can inject more than just nutrients; they can also inject lovely, lovely drugs. Sedatives, muscle relaxants, drugs that screw with emotions... I'm just going to let your imagination think up the rest.

And all this also adds to just how unpleasant and terrifying the Tayan can be. The idea of being trapped in a wet sac, alone and slowly being digested is scary enough. The idea of being trapped in a wet sac, alone, and slowly being digested on top of being wrapped up in constricting tentacles that churn you around and occasionally inject you with god-only-knows-what is pure nightmare fuel.

---

Wait, what? I'm sorry, you want it to have a small flaw that could allow one human to escape? Okay then. Escape from this is *nigh*-impossible, but there is a pretty big emphasis on the *nigh* part of that.

The tentacles may be able to search every inch of the skin, but they can't search underneath the skin. Somebody could surgically implant a knife or other small cutting tool beneath their skin in the event that they were swallowed by a Tayan. If they are flexible enough, they could wiggle out of the tentacles, then use those moments of freedom to whip out the knife (ouch!). They could then use the knife to fend off the tentacles as they climb or cut their way to freedom.

Answer (score 0):

**It Can't**

Sorry for being pessimistic, but I see a few problems you might like to address.
Normally, a stomach is virtually impossible to survive in, due to the lack of oxygen, the crushing and churning action of the stomach walls and the fluid caught between them, and let's not forget the powerful acid.

**However, your creature's innate design eliminate essentially all of those.** For the tentacles to work and keep the prey alive, the prey must be relatively immobile-ergo no crushing and churning. If it takes years to digest, the acid must not be that strong. And if this thing has a large maw, open to the air, then chances are oxygen is a non-issue.

**What you have going for you is** A) the inherent flexibility of the stomach walls, as well as their natural slipperiness, will prevent most would-be escapees; B, the Tayan likely has rows of backward-facing, razor-sharp fangs that would potentially shred escapees, and if I'm correct, the Tayan's mouth is like a lamprey's, a steep ring that would be hard to climb up; and C, the height from the Tayan's bottomless pit to the outside world is likely quite formidable.

Yet, humanity is nothing if not determined, and if something has multiple teeth, and *lives in a desert,* guess what? Teeth will grind down, wear out, fall out, and be replaced. Those teeth will likely fall down into the stomach to be digested and reabsorbed....where a determined human being could potentially use them to climb out.

From the pictures in [How can my creature keep sand out of its mouth?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/124469/how-can-my-creature-keep-sand-out-of-its-mouth), it appears the tentacles will try to ensnare victims, but guess what? If a mom can *lift a car* when adrenalized, you better believe someone will manage to grab a fang, cut themselves free, and escape.

The symbiotic insects mentioned there might complicate this, but then again they may not. Besides being a potential source of free food, their chitin and/or guts could provide valuable acid protection, and if enough of them die in there, the victim could form an island of bugs, even a tower to leap off of!

**So, in conclusion, your Tayan is formidable, but not inescapable in the face of human ingenuity and determination. If I may, I would suggest you account for the Tayan cult's reaction to people escaping the Tayan. Do they chuck them back in?  Exile them? Reward/exalt them? Because chances are, someone's going to do it.**